# Table caption : autonaming and autonumering have disapeared with update 0.8.2

Tags: r, flextable

Using daily this excellent package, I realise that the autonumbering and the word 'Table' have disapeared with the latest update of flextable (0.8.2).

Using example code from the [flextable book](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/captions-and-cross-references.html#knitr-chunk-options-for-flextable-captions), I obtain this html (see image) which shows the abscence of the word 'Table' and the numbers. It shows also that the cross-references are not working.

How can I get the automated naming and numbering back?

Thanks again for your excellent package !

Rmd (from [flextable book](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/captions-and-cross-references.html#knitr-chunk-options-for-flextable-captions))

````
---
title: "flextable caption example"
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(flextable)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
ft <- qflextable(head(airquality))
```

# Captions

Now, let's add a caption with `set_caption`:

```{r ft.align="left"}
library(officer)
set_caption(ft, 
  caption = "airquality dataset", 
  style = "Table Caption", 
  autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = "tab", bkm = "tab1"))
```

Or use kintr chunk options:

```{r ft.align="center", tab.cap='airquality dataset', tab.id='tab2', label='tab2'}
ft
```

# Cross-references

* This is a reference to flextable \@ref(tab:tab1).
* This is a reference to flextable \@ref(tab:tab2).

# Links

* This is a link to [flextable](#tab:tab1)
````

[image]

```
# > sessionInfo()  
# R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=French_Switzerland.utf8 
# [2] LC_CTYPE=French_Switzerland.utf8   
# [3] LC_MONETARY=French_Switzerland.utf8
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       
# [5] LC_TIME=French_Switzerland.utf8    
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] officer_0.4.4   flextable_0.8.2 knitr_1.40     
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        digest_0.6.29     R6_2.5.1         
# [4] grid_4.2.1        evaluate_0.16     zip_2.2.1        
# [7] rlang_1.0.6       gdtools_0.2.4     cli_3.4.0        
# [10] uuid_1.1-0        data.table_1.14.2 rstudioapi_0.14  
# [13] xml2_1.3.3        rmarkdown_2.16    tools_4.2.1      
# [16] xfun_0.33         fastmap_1.1.0     compiler_4.2.1   
# [19] systemfonts_1.0.4 base64enc_0.1-3   htmltools_0.5.3
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's easier to help when there is a reproducible example. I think you don't use bookdown format `bookdown::html_document2`. Cross-references are not implemented with `rmarkdown::html_document`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick clarification. I have updated my question with the code. Adding in the YAML `output: bookdown::html_document2` or `output: officedown::rdocx_document` solved my problem. May I suggest you update the example you give in chapter 6.1.1 of flextable book?

Comment: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/471